# java: cannot access com.mongodb.ServerAddress - java not connecting to MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I tried to connect MongoDB Database to java using the following code.
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.5.0/mongodb-driver-3.5.0.jar - this is the jar file which I added to the java library,I tried other version as well.I'm using Intellij Idea IDE.
    I have already set up the Mongodb server and created a Database. 
    Please propose me a suitable solution.
    Thank you in advance !!

```
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
        System.out.println(" connection successful");

    }
}
```

The following error occurred

```
Error:(10, 35) java: cannot access com.mongodb.ServerAddress
  class file for com.mongodb.ServerAddress not found
C:\Users\IntizarR\IdeaProjects\couseWorkV1\src\MainLogin\Main.java
```

Comment: Please don't bold the whole text of your question. It might attract attention, but none of the attention will actually be good for you. Looks like you have not installed the Java driver properly. You should be using a dependency management system like Maven or Gradle. If you are not, then it's time to learn what those are.

Comment: @NeilLunn thank you ,it was very much helpful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first check that mongodb works fine in command prompt

Comment: When you have sufficient rep you can comment all you want. But answers are for "answers" and this is not what an answer is. We'd also delete it as a "chatty" comment that does not really offer anything constructive. Just so you know.

Comment: I wanted to provide solution after he confirms that server works fine

Comment: it seems that your driver does not contain BSON library try  this:https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/bson/3.5.0/bson-3.5.0.jar

Comment: also add this too:https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/3.5.0/mongodb-driver-core-3.5.0.jar